# Removing items from a list if a predicate holds

Tags: list, haskell, predicate

I am trying to make a function which takes as input a predicate and a list. and removes all elements from the list for which the predicate holds. What I have so far is the following function:

```
removeif :: func->[a]->[a]
removeif [] = []
removeif func (h:t)= if func then delete h (h:t) else removeif func t
```

I am confused about the `func` part of the `func->[a]->[a]` because I don't know how should I tell that its a predicate.

For example what I want is that I give from the terminal this command

```
removeif threefolds [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

`threefolds` is a local function I have and it returns an infinite list with multiples of three and I want to remove those multiples from the input list. I am thinking of making `threefold` a bool function but not sure if that is necessary.

Comment: `removeIf p = filter (not . p)`

Comment: I don't understand the question. A predicate is a function with type `a -> Bool` for some `a`. The condition of `if` needs a `Bool` so there's not much you can do if you want to use code similar to that.

Comment: @Cactus Thank you so much, its  good idea to start with :)

Comment: @Bakuriu Thank you so much, I was confused about it, Now its very clear to me about predicate and how I should continue further. Thank you a millions!!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A predicate should be a function of type `a -> Bool`. Therefore, the signature of `removeif` should be

```
removeif :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

If `threefolds` has type `a -> Bool`, you'll be fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Threefolds should return a boolean, something like this:

```
   let threefolds x =  x `mod` 3 == 0
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it :)

Comment: Then use filter as cactus said in your definition of removeIf: